# error of finding distinct cobinations of muiltiple columns in IBM netezza SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to count a distinct combination number for multiple columns in SQL IBM netteza Aiginity workbench.

```
 id1   id2    id3    id4  id5   id6
 NY    63689  eiof   394  9761   9318
 NY    63689  secf   064  9742   78142
 CT    39631  pfef  92169 9418   9167
 CT    39631  bfbde  23457 10052  618146
```

The result should be

```
 id1   id2    value
 NY    63689  2   
 CT    39631  2
```

I need to find how many distinct combinations of id3,id4,id5 ,id6 for each distinct id2 and id2.

My sql query :

```
 SELECT id1, id2,  
   ( 
      SELECT count(*)  as dis_id_by_id1_id2
      from 
      (
        select distinct id3 , id4 ,id5 ,id6
        FROM my_table 
        group by id1, id2 
      ) t
   ) 
   from my_table
   group by id1, id2
```

I got error:

```
   id3 must be GROUPed or used in an aggregate function
```

If I grouped id3, id4, id5, id6. the result is wrong.

count(distinct id3, id4) is not allowed in IBM netezza.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you first write a query to generate the unique combinations,  then you can use it as a nested sub-query.

Then it's a simple GROUP BY and COUNT().

```
SELECT
  id1,
  id2,
  COUNT(*)   AS value
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6
  FROM
    myTable
  GROUP BY
    id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6
)
  AS uniques
GROUP BY
  id1,
  id2
```

Comment: thanks ! I got results different from what I need. I open a new post about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can do this with arrays and counts:

```
select id1, id2,
       count(distinct string_to_array(id3::text, '') || id4::text || id5::text || id6::text)
from table t
group by id1, id2;
```