# find partial duplicated rows in a SQL table in IBM netezza database

Tags: sql, netezza

This question is related to my previous question :

[error of finding distinct cobinations of muiltiple columns in IBM netezza SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006382/error-of-finding-distinct-cobinations-of-muiltiple-columns-in-ibm-netezza-sql-ta)

Now, I need to find some **partial** duplicated rows in the table in SQL IBM netteza Aiginity workbench.

The table is like :

```
id1   id2    **id3    id4  id5   id6**   id7  id8   id9
NY    63689  eiof   394  9761   9318   2846  2319  215
NY    63689  eiof   394  9761   9318   97614 648   645
CT    39631  pfef  92169 9418   9167   164   3494  34
CT    39631  pfef  92169 9418   9167   3649  7789  568

id3    id4  id5   id6  are duplicated for id1 = NY and id2 = 63689
id3    id4  id5   id6  are duplicated for id1 = CT and id2 = 39631
```

The result should be

```
 id1   id2    value
 NY    63689  2   
 CT    39631  2
```

**UPDATE**: I only need to count the partial duplicated for **id3    id4  id5   id6** for each id1 and id2. I do not care the columns of id7, id8, id9.

I used the sql query:

```
 SELECT  id1,       id2,
  COUNT(*)   AS value
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6
  FROM
    myTable
  GROUP BY
    id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6
)
  AS uniques
GROUP BY
  id1, id2
```

But, I got:

```
   id1   id2    value
   NY    63689  number of combinations of id7  id8   id9   
   CT    39631  number of combinations of id7  id8   id9
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect if you also have 2 rows of "NY    63689  eiof   111 2222 333 2846  2319  215"? I think you need a little bit more variety in your sample data to suss out what you want as a result.

Answer (score 3):

The following query produces the output you want.  Is this what you want to do?

```
SELECT  id1, id2, COUNT(*)   AS value
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id1, id2;
```

EDIT:

If you want complete duplicates (of all columns) but only to show the first two:

```
SELECT  id1, id2, COUNT(*) as value
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6;
```

You can add `having count(*) > 1` if you only want examples with duplicates.

Comment: I have updated the OP and the problem may be a little different now.

Comment: @Gordon linoff, the second solution get the result of all columns including id7/8/9 in my new updated OP. this is not what I want.

Comment: @user3601704 . . . I have no idea what you mean.  ids 7, 8, and 9 are not in either query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the columns of id7/8/9 should not be counted in with id3/4/5/6 columns. In the example of OP, the for NY 63689, it should return 2 as duplicate rows for id3/4/5/6.